# Is there a function to increment timestamp in Python

Tags: python, pandas

We're working with python on an ubuntu 18.04 server, and is storing real time data from temperature sensors on a MySQL database. The database is installed on our server.

What we want to do is to increment a timestamp, where we retrieve the latest value in a 20 min interval, which means that in every 20 min we retrieve the latest temperature value from the sensor, from the MySQL database. We only want the interval to be from .0, 0.20, 0.40.

**Example of the incrementing**

```
2019-07-26 00:00:00
2019-07-26 00:20:00
2019-07-26 00:40:00
2019-07-26 01:00:00
...
2019-07-26 23:40:00
2019-07-27 00:00:00
...
2019-07-30 23:40:00
2019-08-01 00:00:00
```

This is the basic idea of what we want to achieve, but we know this a very bad way of coding thisWe want a more dynamically code. We're imagining that there's a function perhaps, or some other way we haven't thought about. This is what the basic idea looks like:

```
for x in range (0, 24, 1)
    for y in range (0, 60, 20)
        a = pd.read_sql('SELECT temperature1m FROM Weather_Station WHERE timestamp > "2019-07-26 %d:%d:00" AND timestamp < "2019-07-26 %d:%d:00" ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1' % (x, y, x, y+20), conn).astype(float).values
```

On our database we can retrieve first and last timestamp on our sensor.

```
lastLpnTime = pd.read_sql('SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1"', conn).astype(str).values
firstLpnTime = pd.read_sql('SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1"', conn).astype(str).values
```

Therefore we imagine that we can say:

From firstLpnTime to lastLpnTime in a 20 min interval from .00, 0.20 or 0.40 do this retrieve data from the MySQL database

but how we do this?

Comment: How massive is your data? can you read it into pandas then manipulate it? or do you need a sql only solution?

Comment: As of now we have 2400 rows of data. Our sensors are sending data every 15 minutes, so we're not talking massive data flow

Comment: The most important for us is actually the latest 3 values, as we want to measure moving average. Therefore the 3 latest values from x.00, x.20, x.40 is crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the data in pandas dataframe you can sample them in the desired time periods using [pd.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) .

Comment: Thanks, this looks like something we can use! We will look at it ASAP

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, if you want to create a datetimes list you may want to check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html and run sth like this: 
`pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='20T')`

Comment: This works! By saying: 

index = pd.date_range(start=firstLpnTime.min(),end=lastLpnTime.max(),freq='20T')

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand what you need in the first place. Cheers!

Comment: Do you know how we can round down in time , so if the start time is 15:09:25 then start time from 15:00:00. If start time is 15:29:25 then to 15:20:00 and for 15:55:12 to 15:40:00, so we always round down to .00, 0.20 or 0.40

Comment: if `your_start_date = '2019-07-26 13:09:12'` then `your_start_date = pd.to_datetime(your_start_date).round('20T')`

Comment: Thanks , I really appreciate it! .round('20T') seems to round up/down to the nearest. Is there a way to round down for firstLpnTime, and to round up for lastLpnTime?

firstLpnTime: 15:09:25 --> 15:00:00 / lastLpnTime: 17:09:25 --> 15:20:00

Comment: Reduce each timestamp by 10 minutes before rounding and you are good to go. Verify with the code below, changing the minutes.  `your_start_date = '2019-07-26 13:59:00'  
your_start_date = (pd.to_datetime(your_start_date)- datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)).round('20T')  print(your_start_date)`

Comment: You're a hero! when rounding down im subtracting 10, and when rounding up im summing 10. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to increment your timestamp you can do something like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

your_start_date = '2019-07-26 00:00:00'
date = datetime.strptime(your_start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for i in range(10):
    print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    date += increment
```

output:

```
# 2019-07-26 00:00:00
# 2019-07-26 00:20:00
# 2019-07-26 00:40:00
# 2019-07-26 01:00:00
# 2019-07-26 01:20:00
# 2019-07-26 01:40:00
# 2019-07-26 02:00:00
# 2019-07-26 02:20:00
# 2019-07-26 02:40:00
# 2019-07-26 03:00:00
```